# Dismiss AlertDialog opened by another widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I open up a loading dialog in flutter when a user attempts to login, and my main widget is listening to the auth stream to show the HomePage when the user state changes. However the loading dialog remains open on the home page even after the login page is disposed. How can I resolve this? I made a callback function to the login page to call Navigator.of(this.context, rootNavigator: true).pop(); but as you'd imagine, the page is in an unstable state and I get the exception:

> FlutterError (Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. At
> this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
> To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a
> reference to the ancestor by calling
> dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's
> didChangeDependencies() method.)

Need tips fast

Here's the top level of the code. The dialog is opened in the LoginScreen, and needs to be closed on the HomeScreen

```
class AuthWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: _auth.user,
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return SplashScreen();
          }
          if (snapshot.data is User && snapshot.data != null) {
            print(
                "user not null from auth service: ${Provider.of<User>(context)?.uid}");
            return HomeScreen();
          }
          return LoginScreen();
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: So, I'm guessing the loading dialog is in the SplashScreen widget. If that's the case, in the dispose method of SplashScreen, call navigator.pop.

Comment: @rkdupr0n No, it's in the LoginScreen widget. The LoginScreen widget calls a signIn method with firebase and simultaneously shows the dialog, and before the widget lifecycle reaches dispose for the LoginScreen, the firebase authChanged stream alerts the Streambuilder in the ancestor widget that a user is available, and so the HomeScreen shows

Comment: Hmm... Then maybe pass the stream to the login screen and check the connection state there to pop the dialog when it changes?

Comment: Hmm so essentially I should subscribe to the same stream from within the LoginScreen widget and then pop when it detects the same change in user state? I'll try this now, although I feel like it could cause a race condition. Will update

Comment: In that case, I think its best to delay the stream in AuthWrapper by a few seconds. Do update